# Why is mouse accuracy so poor in Blender?

Tags: mouse

Just been trying some tutorials for a few days with Blender and it can be so infurating!

Select this bottom poly (which has been split from the rest of the mesh by pressing Y) then trying to do a loop cut with CTRL+R along the X axis and... you can see from the image that the area the mouse has to be in is just a few pixels!

Also tried in bottom and top (orth) views. No chance.

Why is it so hard?!

Updated link... [Animated GIF](http://acqmail.com/Blender/blender1.gif)

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Would you mind uploading your gif using the [built in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/652639)? The link doesn't work.

Comment: Isolate it and zoom in with the mouse wheel.

Comment: The image attached doesn't open up. Would you mind checking it?

Comment: Hi. Sorry about the link not working. The built in tools didn't like it, I think because it's over 2MB. I've changed the location now.

Comment: make a shorter gif, that will keep it under 2MB